# Trying to establish a linked share connection with SQLite from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sqlite, odbc, linked-server, msdasql

I am trying to create a linked share connection from SQL Server to SQLite. I have followed all the steps by Graham Okely in the below link. It was really nice and I have been able to create the linked share connection from SQL.

[Creating a Linked Server from SQL Server to SQLite to Import the Data](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3087/creating-a-sql-server-linked-server-to-sqlite-to-import-data/)

I have used the sqliteodbc_msvcr100 to install the ODBC driver in my machine. My machine is 32 bit and I have installed the 32 bit ODBC driver.

I am not able to download and extract the other drivers listed in the

http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/

Created the Linked Share Connection by using the below query

```
USE [master]
GO
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver 
   @server = 'SQLite', -- the name you give the server in SSMS 
   @srvproduct = '', -- Can be blank but not NULL
   @provider = 'MSDASQL', 
   @datasrc = 'SQLite' -- the name of the system dsn connection you created
GO
```

But when I tried to access the tables in SQLite using the Openquery

```
Select * from openquery(SQLite, 'select * from Test1')
```

Here the SQLite is my System DSN and Test1 is a table in the SQLite database. But this throws the following error.

> [OLE/DB provider returned message: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified]
>   OLE DB error trace [OLE/DB Provider 'MSDASQL' IDBInitialize::Initialize returned 0x80004005:   ].
>   Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   OLE DB provider 'MSDASQL' reported an error.

Can this be resolved? Please help.

Comment: You left out all information about the ODBC driver and data source.

Comment: Is your SQLServer a 64bit version? [Trouble using 32-bit odbc drivers with 64-bit SQL Server 2008](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/adab1333-2b29-4b73-b3e6-b39d7a3f6773/trouble-using-32bit-odbc-drivers-with-64bit-sql-server-2008?forum=sqldataaccess)

Comment: Have you got any solution to your problem? I am getting the same problem.